# Xslt repeat row after two nodes (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, xml, twitter-bootstrap, xslt

I am still a beginner in xslt.I have trouble creeating rows and columns.

I got an xml like this::

```
<Section Elem="Overview" child="4.0">
  <Section Elem="View 1" child="2.0">
    <Doc Elem="Tab 1">
     <Tit Elem="Code">Tit 1</Tit>
     <Descr Elem="Descr1">Descr 1 </Descr>
    </Doc>
  </Section>   
  <Section Elem="View 2" child="2.0">
    <Doc Elem="Tab 2">
     <Tit Elem="Code">Tit 2</Tit>
     <Descr Elem="Descr2">Descr 2 </Descr>
    </Doc>
  </Section>              
  <Section Elem="View 3" child="0.0">
    <Doc Elem="Tab 3">
     <Tit Elem="Code">Tit 3</Tit>
     <Descr Elem="Descr3">Descr 3 </Descr>
    </Doc>   
  </Section>
  <Section Elem="View 4" child="0.0">
    <Doc Elem="Tab 4">
     <Tit Elem="Code">Tit 4</Tit>
     <Descr Elem="Descr3">Descr 4 </Descr>
    </Doc>   
  </Section>   
</Section>
```

Desired output:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Tit 1</h2>
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Tit 2</h2>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
     <h2>Tit 3</h2>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <h2>Tit 4</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried several things (based on searching on answers given at stackoverflow) but none of them gives me the desired output. 
 like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:template match="Section/Section[position() mod 2 =1]">
    <div class="row">
       <xsl:apply-templates mode="proc" select=".|following-    sibling::Section[not(position() > 2)]" /> 
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Section" mode="proc"> 
      <div class="col-md-6">    
    <h2>   <xsl:value-of select="Tit"/></h2>
      </div>
 </xsl:template>   

  <xsl:template match="Section[not(position() mod 2 = 1)]"/>
```

or what also did not work:

> ```
>   <xsl:param name="pNumCols" select="3"/>
>   <xsl:template match="/">
>  <xsl:apply-templates select="/Sectie[position() mod $columns = 1]"/>
>   </xsl:template>
>
>      <xsl:template match="/Section">      <div class="row">
>     <div class="col-md-6">
>  <xsl:for-each select=".|following-sibling::Section[not(position() > $pNumCols -1)]">         <h2>   <xsl:value-of select="Tit"/></h2>
>  </xsl:for-each>      </div>
>  </div>
> </xsl:template>
> ```

My biggest problem is that I can not repeat the  after two Section parts.

Comment: So why would this question be tagged [tag:css]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Following XSLT 1.0 stylesheet*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Section">
        <removeable>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Section[position() mod 2 = 1]"/>
        </removeable>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Section">
        <div class="row">
            <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::Section[1]" mode="proc"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Section" mode="proc">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>
                <xsl:value-of select="Doc/Tit"/>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*results in*

```
<removeable>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Tit 1</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Tit 2</h2>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Tit 3</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Tit 4</h2>
     </div>
  </div>
</removeable>
```